# How can I convert numeric(16) formatted as yyyyMMddHHmmss00 to Datetime in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, data-conversion

I want to convert start_date numeric(16) to datetime

for example:

> 2023032012121201 to Datetime

I tried this

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(CAST(start_date AS varchar(16)), 1, 8) + ' ' + 
      STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('0000000000' 
      + CAST(start_date AS varchar(16)), 10), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, '.')) 
 FROM table
```

but it gives Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error

Output should be:
2023-03-20T12:12:12.01

Comment: What is `start_date`? What does it actually contain and why do you cast it to `varchar(16)`? There's no reason to cast if it already is a text field. Storing text instead of actual date values is a serious bug to begin with. If you want second precision, use `datetime2(0)`. The precision can be adjusted as need for tens,hundreds of seconds, milliseconds etc

Comment: `2023032012121201` is, presumably, the datetime value `2023-03-20T12:12:12.01`?

Comment: Post the table schema, the definition of `@numeric_date` and sample data. The easiest solution though is to use the correct types

Comment: @ThomA yes it is

Comment: @AaronBertrand it is start date, sorry i edited the question

Comment: I hope that part of your project is to fix the database design and store these values in a datetime datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is a `numeric(16,0)` (or a `varchar(16)`), then you can inject the needed characters ( , `:` and `.`) into the needed positions and then `TRY_CONVERT` that to a `datetime2(2)`. This turns the value into the format `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss.nn` which is an unambiguous date and time format in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @YourString numeric(16,0) = '2023032012121201';
SELECT @YourString,
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(2),STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@YourString,15,0,'.'),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '));
```

I use `TRY_CONVERT` because you *might* have bad data; storing date and time values in anything other than a date and time data type throws validation out the window. As such any such values will return `NULL` instead. Likely you will also want to find and correct such values before you fix your design and change the data type to a date and time data type (`datetime2(2)` seems the right choice here, and why I used it).

Comment: Thank you it worked!! How can I add 1 day after converting to datetime2?

Comment: With `DATEADD`, just like you normally would, @AleynaZengin .#

Comment: @AleynaZengin `DATEADD()` - [documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Seems fine my end, @AaronBertrand . You're not testing in something like in DB<>Fiddle are you? That displays date and time values accurate to 1 second.

Comment: Yes, but why? And why did I never notice that before?

Comment: Heh, I wish i knew, @AaronBertrand . Probably worth a [feedback](https://topanswers.xyz/fiddle?q=2035).

Comment: Why not just use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` and a bit of modulo?

Comment: This was just the route I went down, @Charlieface . There's more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is

```
CREATE tABLe t1(start_date numeric(16) )
```

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2023032012121201 )
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(start_date AS varchar(16)), 1, 8) + ' ' 
  + SUBSTRING(CAST(start_date AS varchar(16)), 9, 2) + ':'
  + SUBSTRING(CAST(start_date AS varchar(16)), 11, 2) + ':'
  + SUBSTRING(CAST(start_date AS varchar(16)), 13, 2) + '.' 
  + SUBSTRING(CAST(start_date AS varchar(16)), 15, 2) AS datetime)  FROM t1
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 2023-03-20 12:12:12.010 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/krfj3wbi)